# Count SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

Hello Have a table like below and I am trying to count the number of Linux and Windows servers I have per Management Address How could one do that:
[image]

Comment: well, you tagged your question with `count`, so you know what you can search for. It doesn't get more straight forward than that

Comment: Sounds like you want a `GROUP BY` expression.  What's a Management Address?  Is that `UCSM`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of these will work.  The second is better, but the first will show you how you can go about this when grouping by isn't so straight-forward (or achievable).

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN OS_NAME = 'Linux' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS [Linux Servers],
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN OS_NAME = 'Windows' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS [Windows Servers]
FROM YourTable

SELECT OS_NAME, COUNT(*)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY OS_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
SELECT UCSM, OS_NAME,  COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY OS_NAME, UCSM
```